# Masonry & multiple WP Queries

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, masonry

I'm using 2 `WP_Query` queries to load a list of posts which I'd like to arrange using masonry. Problem is that masonry is treating each element as though it were too wide to fit the space and is being bumped onto a new line.

If I remove one of the queries masonry works just fine but I need to run 2 queries to load a featured post at a different size.

My code:

```
<div class="contentgrids">

<?php $q1 = new WP_Query($post1);?>
    <?php if ( $q1->have_posts() ) : while ( $q1->have_posts() ) : $q1->the_post(); ?>
       <div class="content_block col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
             <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
             <div class="imager">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
             </div>
             <?php } ?>
             <div class="cont_title">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
             </div>
             <div class="cont_ex">
             <?php the_excerpt ();?>
             </div>
             <div class="cont_pub">
                <?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?>
             </div>
          </a>
       </div> 
    <?php endwhile; endif;?> 
<?php $q2 = new WP_Query($post2);?>
    <?php if ( $q2->have_posts() ) : while ( $q2->have_posts() ) : $q2->the_post(); ?>
       <div class="content_block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="thirds">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
             <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
             <div class="imager">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
             </div>
             <?php } ?>
             <div class="cont_title">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
             </div>
             <div class="cont_ex">
             <?php the_excerpt ();?>
             </div>
             <div class="cont_pub">
                <?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?>
             </div>
          </a>

       </div> 
    <?php endwhile; endif;?> 
</div>
```

Script:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(window).on("load", function(){
                j$('.contentgrids').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.content_block'
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sussed it out!

Masonry uses the width of the first element unless a width is defined for it and as the first element is 66% width, it assumed all elements were that width. I changed the script to include `columnWidth` and it resolved the issue.

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(window).on("load", function(){
                j$('.contentgrids').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.content_block',
                    columnWidth: 1
            });
        });
```